# I want to link each page by a different game_review_id by querystring but it gives me the in any link

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

This is in the source:

`html.Append("<a href = 'http://localhost:50303/WebSite1/previewgamereview.aspx?id=game_review_id'>");`

In the second file I wrote:

`string id = Request.QueryString["id"];`

Comment: You're going to need to be more clear on what your problem is and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html.Append("<a href = 'http://localhost:50303/WebSite1/previewgamereview.aspx?id=" + game_review_id + "'>");
```

In the second file:

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```